# Angular6 and JQuery - layout is not a function with Karma

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-cli, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I'm using a bit of JQuery to work around a visual bug on a library i'm using. 
It's working well, but now that i'm working toward a tested version, i'm faced with an error.

So, in my component, i have :

```
declare var $: any;

@Component({ // })
export class MainComponent {
    constructor() {
        $('body').layout('fix')
    }
}
```

In `karma.conf.js`, i have the following line :

```
files: [
  '../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',   
],
```

And when I launch a `ng test`, there's this error :

```
TypeError: $(...).layout is not a function
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it around document ready.

```
constructor() {
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').layout('fix')
     });
}
```

But I highly recommend using jquery less as possible with angular

Comment: Thanks, that's work perfect. I'm searching for a solution that would avoid JQuery, but to no avail for now.

Comment: Writing `$(document).ready` in angular 2+ is not recommended. Instead use `ngOnInit()` method which exactly serves as `$(document).ready`.

Comment: In this case, `constructor` and `ngOnInit` give the same results if `$(document).ready` isn't precised.

Comment: Use an attribute directive. That will be called once the element rendered. This can be reused in all the components instead of repeating the same code in all the component

Comment: That's... A good idea I think. I'll try that when i've a few time to spare, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Link your JQuery file in `angular.json` file's `scripts` section.

Here is the structure of `angular.json` - https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/aio/angular.json

Also I recommend to write code in `ngOnInit()` method instead of `constructor()`.

Comment: The file is already in angular.json, the app functions correctly, only the tests failed.

Comment: Try writing that code in `ngOnInit()` instead of `constructor()`

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1) In `index.html` put below line in tag.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

2) In component ts file below you have to declare var like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  ngOnInit(){
    $('body').layout('fix'); //
  }

}
```

now you can use it as you want.
if it isn't working with `karma` then try defining it this way:

```
files: [
  { pattern: './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', watched: false },    
]
```

make `watched option false`

Comment: I've edited the title. I think it's kind of misleading as the problem only arises when i'm testing the app.

Comment: @RoadEx check the solution i have provided now

Comment: Worse, i have now a `[object ErrorEvent] thrown` without explaination